# reader-writer task-queue in Android

Tags: java, android, concurrency, task-queue

I am making an android app with `reading tasks` and `writing tasks` .
I want to get the following behavior:

- tasks are executed in a queue
- reading tasks can be run concurrently.
- writing tasks are very important and can not run concurrently, if it is running a writing task can not run any other task of any kind

Iam searching a library that solves this problem.
I could solve this problem semaphores, but I have fear of making a solution to these problems in android.
In my limited experience with android I know it is very difficult to manage the life cycle of these things. And it is very important that writing tasks are executed correctly.

Sorry for my English. Thanks

Comment: do it in java first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [fixed thread pool executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) for your tasks, let all your tasks use the same [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html), and let it work itself out. General example:

```
public class ReadTask implements Runnable {        
    private final ReadWriteLock lock;
    public ReadTask (ReadWriteLock lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }
    @Override public void run () {
        lock.readLock().lock();
        // do stuff
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}

public class WriteTask implements Runnable {
    private final ReadWriteLock lock;
    public WriteTask (ReadWriteLock lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }
    @Override public void run () {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        // do stuff
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

And then, set up your initial executor and lock:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
```

And when you want to queue tasks:

```
// a write task:    
executor.execute(new WriteTask(lock));

// a read task:
executor.execute(new ReadTask(lock));
```

Just make sure you always unlock the locks; you can use a `try ... finally` block if necessary but really since `run()` shouldn't throw any exceptions, you shouldn't be running into issues if you handle everything properly within `run()` as you should.

Comment: It's important to note that this doesn't actually guarantee serial execution, which OP likely wants as he is using a queue. Since the lock is acquired in concurrent code, it is possible that a read task is started before a write task, but the writer grabs the lock first. I'm not aware of an existing Executor implementation that would allow lock acquisition to happen in serial. A hacky solution could use a custom backing queue that acquires the lock in poll() and releases at the end of the runnable.